# Unable to find generated Parcelable class with Realm

Tags: java, android, realm, parcel

I am trying to pass realm object with bundle and I used [Parcel](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) library

This is my realm model class.
Album.java

```
@Parcel
public class Album extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
@PrimaryKey
  public String id;
  public String upc;
  public String albumName;
  public String albumArtUrl;
  public String artistName;
  public String genre_id;
  public String genreName;
  public String price;
  public String releaseYear;
  public int explicit;
  public RealmList<Song> songs = new RealmList<>();
}
```

And this is Song.java.

```
@Parcel
public class Song extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
  @PrimaryKey
  public String id;
  public String isrc;
  public String songName;
  public String artistName;
  public String album_id;
  public String albumArtUrl;
  public String genre_id;
  public String genreName;
  public String releaseYear;
  public String price;
  public String lyrics;
  public String demo;
  public int explicit;
}
```

When I try to pass album object in bundle like that,

```
b.putParcelable("album", Parcels.wrap(album));
```

I am having that error.

```
Unable to find generated Parcelable class for com.devhousemyanmar.juketrill.models.Album, verify that your class is configured properly and that the Parcelable class com.devhousemyanmar.juketrill.models.Album$$Parcelable is generated by Parceler.
```

please help me to solve this.

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3915#issuecomment-267276942

Comment: @Mr.Hyde thats not the problem with Serializable i guess. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1281 ;;;; https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#gson

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation, it has a section dedicated to [using Parceler](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#parceler).

```
// All classes that extend RealmObject will have a matching RealmProxy class created
// by the annotation processor. Parceler must be made aware of this class. Note that
// the class is not available until the project has been compiled at least once.
@Parcel(implementations = { PersonRealmProxy.class },
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, // <-- requires getters/setters if set
        analyze = { Person.class })
public class Person extends RealmObject {
    // ...
}
```

But what's worth noting is that you don't need to specify `implementations = {PersonRealmProxy.class}` if you use `realm.copyFromRealm(song)` before passing it to `Parcels.wrap()`. You'll need to do that anyways if you want to use field values instead of `bean` serialization strategy, anyways.

Also, you might need [a RealmList parceler configuration](https://gist.github.com/Rexee/3ec92b759b3a944d4ad4b28666b2479c).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206007/unable-to-find-generated-parcelable-class?answertab=active#tab-top
I tried like u suggested me. But that error still happening to me.
Could you please help me to solve this?