# Unable to find generated Parcelable class

Tags: android, realm, parceler

I am trying to use Parceler in my android project.
This is my Song model.

```
@Parcel(implementations = {SongRealmProxy.class},
       value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
       analyze = {Song.class})
public class Song extends RealmObject {

  @PrimaryKey
  public String id;
  public String isrc;
  public String songName;
  public String artistName;
  public String album_id;
  public String albumArtUrl;
  public String genre_id;
  public String genreName;
  public String releaseYear;
  public String price;
  public String lyrics;
  public String demo;
  public int explicit;
}
```

When I try to warp these song model using bundle like this.

```
b.putParcelable(DATA_PARAM, Parcels.wrap(song));
```

I keep having this error.

```
org.parceler.ParcelerRuntimeException: Unable to find generated Parcelable class for com.devhousemyanmar.juketrill.models.Song, verify that your class is configured properly and that the Parcelable class com.devhousemyanmar.juketrill.models.Song$$Parcelable is generated by Parceler.
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Configuration looks correct, are you using proguard?

Comment: No, I haven't used proguard yet. @JohnEricksen

Comment: Next thing to check is that you have the Parceler annotation processor in your build and it actually builds java files.  Can you check your gradle build and the temporary build output location?

Answer (score -1):

Parcelable class should be like this :

package com.yourpackagename;

```
public class BrushData implements Parcelable {

    public static final Creator<BrushData> CREATOR = new Creator<BrushData>() {
        @Override
        public BrushData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new BrushData(in);
        }

        @Override
        public BrushData[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BrushData[size];
        }
    };
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    @SerializedName("icon")
    private String icon;
    @SerializedName("effects")
    private ArrayList<String> effects;

    private BrushData(Parcel parcel) {
        if (parcel != null) {
            readFromParcel(parcel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        if (in.readInt() == VERSION) {
            icon = in.readString();
        }
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(VERSION);
        parcel.writeString(icon);
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getEffects() {
        return effects;
    }

    public void setEffects(ArrayList<String> effects) {
        this.effects = effects;
    }

}
```

Comment: No, I am using that parceler.
https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler trying to parcel my realmObjects.

Comment: @MinKhantLu did you get any solution

Comment: @saintjab I decided to use another way rather than this.